# Android toolbar custom image view icon with drop down list

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to provide a numbered month's list dropdown with calendar icon click on the app toolbar. I am having two issues/questions to implement this.

1. **Unable to place calendar, icon with out disturbing the title (*NavHost traversed fragment names*)**.
2. **Don't know how to show a clickable drop down list with some options on that icon**

With the help of internet, I have implemented single activity and multi fragment (Jetpack navigation) architecture app as shown in below image.

Below is the code I have tried to implement this:

[image]

And here is App screenshots with different behaviors

[image]

When I uncomment above code (21 to 35), I see 1 and 3 of below images and If I comment that ou, I see 2 and 4.

For the first issue, is it just a UI trick to update the RelativeLayout width to warp_content of child ? or any other way to achieve this properly.

For the second issue, I didn't find a one step or atleast two step solution. Every where it shows Navigation menu option, when I try for "Android toolbar clickable dropdown list".

***My Final goal:***  *Show a calendar icon with months list click able dropdown (1 month, 3 months, 6 months, 9months ... e.t.c) on the right side of the toolbar when user lands on Invoices page for filtering*

Answer (score 0):

1. Make this in xml layout file:

   ```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            style="@style/MyTheme.ToolbarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingStart="12dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingEnd="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            app:title="@string/app_name"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/yourImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_your_icon" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
   ```
2. You need use popup menu. Make xml file for menu. For example:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/month1"
            android:title="1month" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/months3"
            android:title="3months" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/months6"
           android:title="6months" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/months9"
            android:title="9months" />
    </menu>
   ```

And than use menu in activity. Create instance of popup menu, set listener for it and set listener for youe image. Write this in `onCreate` function:

```
   ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.yourImageView);
   PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, image);
   popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_your_name, popupMenu.getMenu());
   popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
       public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
           //Do what you want
           return true;
       }
   });
   image.setOnClickListener(view->{
       popupMenu.show();
   });
```

May be this is not the most optimal way, but it must be work as you want.

Comment: I figured out with sub menu option way. Thanks for your other approach suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, for my `multiple fragment and single activity architecture ("Jetpack navigation") related menu/custom action icons in toolbar`

*Note: Below 1,2,3 helps to solve above problem statement 1 and the remaining helps 2*

1. Create another menu file with required content.
2. Populate it with `onCreateMenuOptions in the desired fragment

   - (*Note: Include `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in the onCreate*)
   - If you inflate a menu in this onCreateMenuOptions, you new menu will be appended to the already existing one of parent/main activity inflated.

```kotlin
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.invoice_list_menu, menu)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
```

}

3. Create a sub menu. in the menu item with radio checkable group. See the last screenshot for example
4. override `onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem)` to capture the menu clicks. Make sure you are updating the checkable status of the radio item.
5. Note: Make sure you are using the `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"` from above 2nd link, to get the proper white overlayed nice action bar. Otherwise you will end up having some dark text colored action bar with out known why

Below links are helpful to understand more:

- [Android developers docs Menu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus) (To understand things inside menu)
- [Android material menu action bar implementation](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Extended-ActionBar-Guide) (To create a proper action bar with material design compatible)
- [Extended ActionBar guide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/index.html#0) (To add search to toolbar and create collapsable toolbar )
- [Android Jetpack Navigation example contained menu usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcbEx.jpg)

Below screenshot is the final output and code reference

[image]

[image]